# max likelihood fminsearch

Tags: matlab, math

I used Matlab-fminsearch for a negativ max likelihood  model for a binomial distributed function. I don't get any error notice, but the parameter which I want to estimate, take always the start value. Apparently, there is a mistake. I know that I ask a totally general question. But is it possible that anybody had the same mistake and know how to deal with it?
Thanks a lot,

@woodchips, thank you a lot. Step by step, I've tried to do what you advised me. First of all, I actually maximized (-log(likelihood)) and this is not the problem. I think I found out the problem but I still have some questions, if I don't bother you. I have a model(param) to maximize in paramstart=p1. This model is built for (-log(likelihood(F))) and my F is a  vectorized function like F(t,Z,X,T,param,m2,m3,k,l). I have a data like (tdata,kdata,ldata),X,T are grids and Z is a function on this grid and (m1,m2,m3) are given parameters.When I want to see the value of F(tdata,Z,X,T,m1,m2,m3,kdata,ldata), I get a good output. But I think fminsearch accept that F(tdata,Z,X,T,p,m2,m3,kdata,ldata) like a constant and thatswhy I always have as estimated parameter the start value. I will be happy, if you have any advise to tweak that.

Comment: I think you need to read through the demos and help for fminsearch. IT has many examples of how to use it. In this case, it appears that fminsearch does not know which parameters you want to optimize over. Again, look at the examples, and follow them.

Answer (score 2):

You have some options you can try to tweak. I'd start with algorithm.

When the function value practically doesn't change around your startpoint it's also problematic. Maybe switching to log-likelyhood helps.

I always use `fminunc` or `fmincon`. They allow also providing the Hessian (typically better than "estimated") or 'typical values' so the algorithm doesn't spend time in unfeasible regions.

Answer (score 1):

It is virtually always true that you should NEVER maximize a likelihood function, but ALWAYS maximize the log of that function. Floating point issues will almost always corrupt the problem otherwise. That your optimization starts and stops at the same point is a good indicator this is the problem.

You may well need to dig a little deeper than the above, but even so, this next test is the test I recommend that all users of optimization tools do for every one of their problems, BEFORE they throw a function into an optimizer. Evaluate your objective for several points in the vicinity. Does it yield significantly different values? If not, then look to see why not. Are you creating a non-smooth objective to optimize, or a zero objective? I.e., zero to within the supplied tolerances?

If it does yield different values but still not converge, then make sure you know how to call the optimizer correctly. Yeah, right, like nobody has ever made this mistake before. This is actually a very common cause of failure of optimizers.

If it does yield good values that vary, and you ARE calling the optimizer correctly, then think if there are regions into which the optimizer is trying to diverge that yield garbage results. Is the objective generating complex or imaginary results?

Comment: thank you a lot. If I don't bother you, could you please help me for my stack. I wrote it under the same question.